# Wampserver - The ServerName localhost:7979 is not defined into hosts file

Tags: wampserver

> [WampServer Virtual Hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48TV5.png)

Here's the config file - `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
'''
<VirtualHost *:7979>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Host's file - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

I can access my project's fine, it's just on the homepage it's bringing this error.

Comment: First, why did you change the port number?

Comment: port number 8080 was used

Comment: The default port number is 80 and that is what is set in `httpd.conf` if you leave it as 80, chances are things will just work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Windows Hosts File]

Looks like the port number had to been included like the image above on the hosts file, no error messages now.

Comment: How is this different from Mohamed's answer?

Answer (score 6):

at your Host's file - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, you can add or edit your first line:

`127.0.0.1 localhost:7979`

Answer (score 0):

There is a process for adding port numbers to WAMPServer.

Using the wampmanager.exe icon in the system tray do the following

```
Right click wampmanager icon -> Tools -> Add a Listen port to Apache
```

[image]

This will throw a little dialog onto the screen, enter the port number you want to use, and that will be added to the `httpd.conf` file like this

```
Define MYPORT8082 8082
```

Into this section of the `httpd.conf` file

Like this

```
Define APACHE24 Apache2.4
Define VERSION_APACHE 2.4.52
Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp64
Define APACHE_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
Define MYPORT8082 8082
Define SRVROOT ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
```

If you add your port number like that, then change the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file to use the define on the VirtualHosts definition

```
<VirtualHost *:${MYPORT8082}>
```